# what is the relation between Sh(SpecA) and $O_{SpecA}$-Mod

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

We consider category of sheaf of $SpecA$.$O_{SpecA}$-Mod represents the sheaf of module.
There is a natural forgetful functor $U$ from the sheaf of modules to $Sh(SpecA)$.this is a exact functor.

- I wonder is there another functor from $Sh(SpecA)$ to the sheaf of modules such that it is the left adjoint of $U$?

I think in general,this is not right.for any sheaf $F$,there exists a $A$ module $M$ such that $F=M$~ maybe ridiculous.
If $U$ don't have left adjoint,this is also interesting!

- is there some particular ring make this true?

Comment: Yes there is a left adjoint $L$. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$. Then $L(\mathcal{F})$ is the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\mapsto \mathcal{O}_X(U).\mathcal{F}(U)$ where $\mathcal{O}_X(U).\mathcal{F}(U)$ is the free $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module spanned by $\mathcal{F}(U)$. It works for any ringed space, not only $\operatorname{Spec}A$. But note that this sheaf is in general not a quasi-coherent sheaf. Did you wanted a left adjoint to $\operatorname{QCoh}(A)\rightarrow\operatorname{Sh}(\operatorname{Spec}A)$.

Comment: @Roland yeah,it maybe not quasi-coherent.for SpecA,$QCoh(A)$ is equivalent to $O_{SpecA}$-Mod,is this right?

Comment: No, $\operatorname{QCoh}(A)$ is equivalent to $A-\operatorname{Mod}$, but not to $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}-\operatorname{Mod}$. The latter category is much bigger : on any open set $\operatorname{Spec}A_f$ you can choose any $A_f$-module, not necessarily $M_f$.

Comment: @Roland you re right,I understand wrong before.

Comment: @Roland if we consider $Qch(A)$,is there a left adjoint?

Comment: No, the inclusion $QCoh(X)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X-Mod$ does not have a left adjoint in general (even in the affine case). It does have a right adjoint though (under mild hypothesis) : in the affine case it is $\mathcal{F}\mapsto\widetilde{\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})}$. But this does not combine to get a left adjoint to the forgetful functor $QCoh(X)\rightarrow Sh(X)$.

Comment: @Roland thank you so much!I will try to understand the relation between them.

Comment: Well of course there are some rings where this is true : if $A$ is a field for instance. But I don't know any criteria. Surely what you need is the following : if $(M_i)$ are a family of $A$-module, then $\widetilde{\prod M_i}=\prod \widetilde{M_i}$ where in the latter, the product means the product in the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (or sheaves). But it seems quite restrictive...

Comment: @Roland yeah,yeah!I think the problem of infinite product of this for two days!This is not true in general.what I really want to find is a class of short exact sequence of sheaves,but infinite product is not exact of sheaves.do you have good examples?

Comment: @Roland in category of sheaves of modules.infinite product is exact.

Comment: No, even in the category of sheaves of modules, infinite product are not exact. Of course, infinite product are left exact, so it is enough to find an infinite product of epis which is not an epi. The following works : take epimorphisms $\mathcal{F}_i\rightarrow\mathcal{G}_i$ with a family of section $g_i$ such that preimage of the $g_i$ are defined only on arbitrary small subset. Then the product $\prod\mathcal{F}_i\rightarrow\prod\mathcal{G}_i$ is not epi since $(g_i)$ does not belong to the image.

Comment: You can construct such an example in the category of modules with $\mathcal{F}_i=\bigoplus_j {v_{ij}}_!\mathcal{O}_{U_{ij}}$ and $\mathcal{G}_i=\mathcal{O}_X$ where $U_{ij}$ is an open cover of $X$ (getting smaller and smaller when $i\rightarrow +\infty$) and $v_{ij}$ being the inclusion map : $U_{ij}\rightarrow X$.

Comment: @Roland oh，what a shameful my mistake.I still think the object of sheaves of modules are induced by a module!interesting construction!I really don't understand what your construction at the last.let me think for some time.thank you for your patients!